# jbd2/sda2-8 utilizing disk I/O and Xorg.0.log log

Tags: linux, centos, xorg, iotop

I noticed that `jbd2/sda2-8` is always using disk and `iotop` showing IO% between 1%-5%.

I checked the logs and noticed Xorg.0.log quite large. I see there are frequent connection and disconnection. Is there a way to reduce this.

```
[root@vmcloudm51 autoit]# tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[177501.285] AUDIT: Tue Feb 28 14:00:23 2023: 3444: client 19 disconnected
[177531.342] AUDIT: Tue Feb 28 14:00:53 2023: 3444: client 19 connected from local host ( uid=986 gid=1009 pid=29884 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 919
[177531.343] AUDIT: Tue Feb 28 14:00:53 2023: 3444: client 19 disconnected
[177561.398] AUDIT: Tue Feb 28 14:01:23 2023: 3444: client 19 connected from local host ( uid=986 gid=1009 pid=29884 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 919
[177561.399] AUDIT: Tue Feb 28 14:01:23 2023: 3444: client 19 disconnected
[177591.541] AUDIT: Tue Feb 28 14:01:53 2023: 3444: client 19 connected from local host ( uid=986 gid=1009 pid=29884 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 919
[177591.557] AUDIT: Tue Feb 28 14:01:53 2023: 3444: client 19 disconnected
[177621.616] AUDIT: Tue Feb 28 14:02:23 2023: 3444: client 19 connected from local host ( uid=986 gid=1009 pid=29884 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 919
[177621.617] AUDIT: Tue Feb 28 14:02:23 2023: 3444: client 19 disconnected
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cause, but there is an option **-audit *number*** to the Xorg server that can be used to get these sort of messages on stderr.  See `man Xserver`. If you can see this option on the process command line with a value of `2` or more, you need to find where it is being set and change it to 1 or 0:

> The default level is 1, meaning only connection rejections are reported.
> Level 2 additionally reports all successful connections and disconnects.
> [...] Level 0 turns off the audit trail. Audit lines are sent as standard
> error output.